# how to give priority of jar file in tomcat classpath

Tags: java

I have 2 jar file let say name is 1) Json.jar 2) javapns.jar with 1 class (eg. Jsonobject) having same package name. 
I want both the jar file in my project. 
I want to use Jsonobject in my class from json.jar file but in tomcat it is referring to javapns.jar file. how can I refer to Json.jar file? I must need both the jar files. Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat class loader order documentation may help
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/class-loader-howto.html#Class_Loader_Definitions